# Pivot table calculated item produces error

Tags: vba, excel

I have two different worksheets (Input1 and Input2) and I am writing a piece of code to build a report. My Code runs successfully on Input1 - worksheet but not on Input 2 - Worksheet.

This is my data - INPUT 1

```
Model       Date      Product     Payment   Mode
Blackberry  1/31/2010   Watch     Card      Online
Blackberry  2/1/2010    TV        Card      Online
Blackberry  1/31/2010   Watch     Cash      Online
Blackberry  2/3/2010    TV        Card      Online
Blackberry  2/4/2010    TV        Cash      Online
Blackberry  1/31/2010   Mobile    Cash      Store
Apple       2/6/2010    HeadPhone Cash      Store
Apple       1/31/2010   Watch     Cash      Store
Apple       2/8/2010    Watch     Cash      Store
```

I am trying to build a Pivot table that makes use of two calculated fields.

- Seller1 which just adds Mobile and Headphones
- Seller2 which adds TV and Watch.

In Input2, I don't have a headphone. So, the code that worked for Input1 is not working.

```
     Cells.Select
        ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
            "Input1!R1C1:R1048576C5", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12).CreatePivotTable _
            TableDestination:="Output1!R8C2:R20C14", TableName:="PivotTable2", _
            DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion12
        Sheets("Output1").Select

        With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Product")
            .Orientation = xlColumnField
            .Position = 1
        End With

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField 
ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
            "PivotTable2").PivotFields("Model"), "Count of Model", xlCount
        Range("C9").Select    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Product").CalculatedItems. _
            Add "Seller1", "=Mobile +HeadPhone", True


ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Product").CalculatedItems. _
        Add "Seller2", "=Watch +TV", True
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Product")
        .PivotItems("HeadPhone").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Mobile").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("TV").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Watch").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Watch ").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End With

    End Sub
```

This is the Output that I am looking for - [image: Output Required]

Comment: I tried to change the data-source from Input1 to Input2 and found out it was the problem with the headphone data and the code is not dynamic enough...Kindly do share your views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it just ".PivotItems('HeadPhone').Visible = False" that is creating the error? The simplest fix would be to not include this item. However you can make your code far more dynamic with a few tweaks:

```
        Dim wb as Workbook

        ' Use variables, they are more accurate and it helps make your code
        ' more dynamic.
        Dim wsIn_1 as Worksheet, wsIn_2 as Worksheet, _
        wsOut_1 as Worksheet, wsOut_2 as Worksheet

        Dim pt1 as PivotTable, pt2 as PivotTable

        ' For use in looping pivotitems if you need to
        Dim pi as PivotItem


        Dim sCalculate as String

        ' Set it however you wish, this just prompts the user.
        sCalculate = Inputbox("Please enter the formula you would like to use.")
        ' Assumes that workbook running code is the same one being edited.
        Set wb = ThisWorkbook

        ' Set the worksheet variables
        With wb
            Set wsIn_1 = .Sheets("Input1")
            Set wsIn_2 = .Sheets("Input2")
            Set wsOut_1 = .Sheets("Output1")
            Set wsOut_2 = .Sheets("Output2")
        End With

        ' Always name your pivot tables. It is good practice. In this case
        ' I created a generic name but you can make something more precise.
        wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
            "Input1!R1C1:R1048576C5", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12).CreatePivotTable _
            TableDestination:="Output1!R8C2:R20C14", TableName:="pt_Output_1", _
            DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion12

        ' It is best to avoid activate and select, but I am including it
        ' in case it is somehow important for the sheet to be active on the
        ' so you can see the code running. No need to activate it just to work
        ' on it though.
        wsOut_1.Activate

        With wsOut_1.PivotTables("pt_Output_1").PivotFields("Product")
            .Orientation = xlColumnField
            .Position = 1
        End With

        Set pt2 = wsOut_1.PivotTables("PivotTable2")

        With pt2
            .AddDataField 
            .PivotFields("Model"), "Count of Model", xlCount    
            ' All you need to do is replace the string within the code with a string variable
            ' It would be ideal to have some kind of data validation in here to ensure
            ' only valid strings can be passed in. You will also need to somehow ensure
            ' that you are entering an appropriate formula.
            .PivotFields("Product").CalculatedItems.Add "Seller1", sCalculate, True
            .PivotFields("Product").CalculatedItems.Add "Seller2", "=Watch +TV", True


            ' I commented out the entire block below since I dont think this
            ' is what you are trying to accomplish. Instead use this:

            .PivotFields("Product").Visible = xlHidden

            ' With .PivotFields("Product")
                ' Since it looks like you are simply hiding everything
                ' use a for loop instead.

                ' I have made kept all of this commented out because
                ' because you will run into an error if there isn't at
                ' least one visible item.

                ' For each pi in .PivotItems
                '     pi.Visible = False
                ' Next
                ' .PivotItems("HeadPhone").Visible = False
                ' .PivotItems("Mobile").Visible = False
                ' .PivotItems("TV").Visible = False
                ' .PivotItems("Watch").Visible = False
                ' .PivotItems("Watch ").Visible = False
                ' .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
           ' End With
        End With

    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No, Its actually this line where we kind of add "Seller1", = "Mobile+HeadPhone", True . Because it doesn't exist it throws an error

Comment: What do you want to add instead then? If you can't add it, then just remove the line or replace it with what you want to add that works. If you instead want to be able to dynamically change the field you could use a string variable.

Comment: Yup ! The String variable is what I am actually looking for, but just don't know how to do it. Please help me with that

Comment: Oh, that should be super simple. See my revised code.

Comment: Thanks ! You are a Super man !! I will wait for the changes to reflect in the revised code..It hasn't yet though

Comment: Sorry, I commented before editing. You should see them now. Basically, all you need to do is replace the string within the arguments with the string you want to use. I didn't use any error checking, data validation, etc. This is just a proof of concept. You will want to practice and develop your code a bit further to ensure only valid formulas can be passed in.

Comment: Thank you Sir. I will develop the rest ! Thanks a million

Comment: Not a problem at all :). Good luck!

Comment: Nice, you can have a better use of your `With Ppt2` , the following line you have `.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Model"), "Count of Model", xlCount`, you can just write `.PivotFields("Model"), "Count of Model", xlCount`

Comment: Good catch. Adjusted the references within the with block.